# Binary file not working in c++

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, file-handling, ofstream

I am trying to create a binary file to store objects of Student class. But the write() function doesn't seem to work. When I call the function to write data into the file, it accepts the data. But, when I query to show the content of file the data does not show. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Student
{
    int marks;
    public:
    void get()
    {
        cin>>marks;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<marks<<endl;
    }        
};

void writ()
{
    ofstream f1;
    f1.open("record.dat",ios::app|ios::binary);
    Student ob;
    ob.get();
    f1.write((char*)&ob,sizeof(ob));
    f1.close();
}

void rea()
{
    ifstream f2;
    f2.open("record.dat",ios::in|ios::binary);
    Student ob;
    while(f2.read((char*)&ob,sizeof(ob)))
    {
        ob.show();
    }
    cout<<"EOF\n";
    f2.close();
}

int main()
{
    int ch;
    do
    {
        cout<<"1-enter data"<<endl;
        cout<<"2-show data"<<endl;
        cout<<"3-Exit"<<endl;
        cin>>ch;
        cout<<"\n\n";
        if(ch==1)
            writ();
        else if(ch==2)
            rea();
        else
            break;
    }while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know "it accepts the data" when you don't check whether the write succeeded, or even if you opened the file successfully?

Comment: You can't binary dump classes like that and expect it to always work. Create << >> operators.

Comment: Your `Student` class currently contains a single int.  I'm sure it will get more robust -- then there are more chances that this technique of binary read/write of the object will no longer work correctly.

Comment: Research "c++ serialization Boost".  The writing of an object, using unformatted writes, is called "serialization".

Comment: By the way, short length identifiers do not speed up your program, nor do they have a noticeable impact on build time.  So make your program readable and easier to maintain, use longer identifiers or go to http:://www.thesaurus.com.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Agreed, if nothing else it'll break in strange and horrible ways the instant `class Student` contains a virtual method.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, using multiple data members in the class worked out fine! Can you shed some more light as to why this happens?

Comment: @NikhilEm - It depends on the types you have in your `Student` class.  If you add a `std::string` for the student's name, then the code to do binary read/writes is no longer valid.  In general, if `Student` is not a POD type, then you can't read/write the object to a file in this manner.